# Android - Can services start activities in closed apps

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, android-service

**Question -**
Is it possible to use a service to start an application AND bring the user to a particular activity, which is not the main activity? Essentially, I am building an alert system, so I need this to work regardless if the application is closed or suspended.

**Application Info -**
In my application, I would like to run a service that checks the state of a device every 30 seconds. If the state of the device matches one of my defined alert conditions, I would like my application to wake the phone, bring the user to an activity (not main), then kill the service. The service will begin again later once the user handles the condition.

I am targeting API 19+, so I must use services, rather than the scheduler (for now). If the above answer is yes, I have to assume that a Start Service would be better than a Bound? Additionally, an IntentService seems capable of stopping itself after the work is done, which would be to wake the phone and bring it to an activity. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. If you start an application, which starts a service, you may kill the application completely and the service will run in the background. Further, when the service starts an activity, it may start any activity.

The best service to use in my case was a start service combined with a thread. Every 30 seconds, the thread can do some work without halting user activity. Once my condition was met, the thread can stop the service itself.

Lastly, to wake up an applicaion, you simply need a few lines of code in the onCreate() method of the activity:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Keeping the screen on is optional - but preferred for my type of alert.

Happy Coding -